# How to run 2 commands from 1 line

Tags: batch-file, command, call

I have 2 lines of code.
I need the 1st line to run and while it is still running start the 2nd.
The first line runs a powershell script that keeps the pc active.
The second goes to the main script.
No matter how I adjust it, it runs the 1st line and doesnt go to the 2nd.
&, &&, | have not worked when combining to 1 line.
Running separately, they work but I need it to go back to Master when the 1st script starts
I forgot to mention, the  powershell script is a repeating script that sends characters and never end till you stop it.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File \\XXX-XXXXX\share\public\it\Scripts_For_Workstations\scripts\keep_alive\mouse1.ps1 
 call \\XXX-XXXXX\share\public\it\Scripts_For_Workstations\XXXXXX_Master_Script.bat :SUB_Start
```

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at the `Start` command as a way to invoke a new instance of the Comspec. [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: Example line 1 ```Start "mouse1" %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "\\XXX-XXXXX\share\public\it\Scripts_For_Workstations\scripts\keep_alive\mouse1.ps1"```

Comment: Compo That worked perfect. I would mark it as the answer if I could figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 2 files at once, whitch contains one line of commands, here is an example:

EXAMPLE 1:

**Main file**:
`@echo off cls start file1 start file2 cls <Perform some actions>`

**File1**:
`<Perform some action>`

**File2**:
`<Perform some action>`

EXAMPLE 2:

**Main file**:

`@echo off cls start file1 cls <Perform some actions>`

**File1**:
`<Perform some action>`